# How to check online status in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-connection, network-connection

I have created a function that checks if the application is online or not. However, based on the MDN documentation, `navigator.onLine` is giving false positives on Chrome and Safari which I'm currently experiencing right now. Is there any other way to resolve this current issue?

useOnlineStatus.ts:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const getOnlineStatus = (): boolean => {
  return typeof navigator !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof navigator.onLine === 'boolean'
    ? navigator.onLine
    : true
}

const useOnlineStatus = (): boolean => {
  const [onlineStatus, setOnlineStatus] = useState(getOnlineStatus())

  const goOnline = () => setOnlineStatus(true)

  const goOffline = () => setOnlineStatus(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('online', goOnline)
    window.addEventListener('offline', goOffline)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', goOnline)
      window.removeEventListener('offline', goOffline)
    }
  }, [])

  return onlineStatus
}

export default useOnlineStatus
```

Comment: How are you testing?

Comment: I tried disconnecting on a WiFi or any LAN connection and changing the Network Throttling Profile from 'No throttling' to 'Offline'

Comment: Change network throttling profile works but not on disconnecting a WiFi or any LAN connection.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could try is to send a request to your own origin to check whether your application is online or not.

The query params (q) is randomised to avoid cached responses.

```
const isAppOnline = async() => {
  if (!window.navigator.onLine) return false

  const url = new URL(window.location.origin)
  url.searchParams.set('q', new Date().toString())

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      url.toString(),
      { method: 'HEAD' },
    )

    return response.ok
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something very similar. 
However, you do not have to add the queryparameters. 
The fetch method has a prop you can set: cache: "no-store". This way the fetch will always go to the origin without cache of the response. 
So `await fetch(URL, {
method: 'HEAD',
cache: 'no-store'
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can custom useEffect like this

```
const useIsomorphicLayoutEffect = typeof window !== "undefined" ? useLayoutEffect : useEffect;
```

and then set navigator inside function "useIsomorphicLayoutEffect" like this

```
useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
console.log(navigator.onLine ? "Online" : "OFFline");
});
```

hope this helps